# Convert PHP session (+ referral data) script to ASP.NET

Tags: php, asp.net, session, referrer

This is a PHP script I use to get the referring website for each new visitor to my site.

If the visitor came from Google, I get the keyword they used to find the site.

This data is stored in the session then included along with the data from the contact form when an enquiry is sent. This allows clients with little knowledge of analytics to track converting keywords.

**I need to convert this PHP to work on a site that uses .aspx pages.** After researching asp.net for several hours, I feel like I still don't have a clue where to start!

```
<code>
    <?php
    session_start(); // start up your PHP session!

    if (empty($_SESSION['google'])) {
    // if session is empty, take the referer
    $thereferer = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    // see if it comes from google
    if (strpos($thereferer,"google")) {
    // delete all before q=
    $a = substr($thereferer, strpos($thereferer,"q="));
    // delete q=
    $a = substr($a,2);
    // delete all FROM the next & onwards
    if (strpos($a,"&")) {
        $a = substr($a, 0,strpos($a,"&"));
    }   
    // we have the key phrase
    $_SESSION['google'] = urldecode($a);
    $_SESSION['referer'] = 'Google';
    }
    }

    if (empty($_SESSION['referer'])) {
    $_SESSION['referer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    }
    ?>
</code>
```

I'd really appreciate a point in the right direction with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on the [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) and [HttpResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx) classes. More specifically, the `Request.ServerVariables` collection, the `Request.Cookies` object, and the `Response.Cookies` object.